# How do I open multiple Excel files using Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, excel, parsing

I am working on writing a ruby script to iterate through a file containing a list of file paths to open in *Microsoft Excel*. I read the file like this:

```
file_names = IO.readlines('D:\TEST_1\file_names.txt')
```

Next, I create an array of file names from each line of the parsed file (thus containing an array of file paths). Finally, I loop through that array with the following code, to open the documents:

```
require 'win32ole'
xl = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible = 1
file_names.each do |file_name|
wb1=xl.Workbooks.Open(file_name)
ws1=wb1.worksheets(1)
end
```

That first call to parse `file_names.txt` produces this exception, which I am having difficulty understanding:

> Test4.rb:6:in 'method_missing' 
>    OLE error code:800A03EC in Microsoft Office
>   Excel 'D:\Test_1\1.xlsx' couldnot be found. Check the spelling of
>   the file name, and verify that the file location is correct.
>
> if you are trying to open the file from your list most recently used
>   files, make sure that the file has not been renamed, moved or deleted
>   HR Error code : 0x80020009 Exception occurred. from Test4.rb:6:in
>   'block in ' from Test4.rb:5:in 'each' from Test4.rb:5:in
>   ''

This error does not appear when I pass a single file name (instead of a file path) as my parameter - so why do I get it here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

At first look you are not using the variable "file_name" but a symbol :file_name.

```
file_array.each do |file_name|
  wb1=xl.Workbooks.Open(file_name)
  ws1=wb1.worksheets(1)
end
```

Comment: I have changed the edit while troubleshooting i tried symbols..even with variable I have same issue...